# How to enable Swagger and add a debug constant for asp.net during CI/CD Azure DevOps

Tags: asp.net, azure, continuous-integration, swagger, devops

I am not able to enable the Debug constant when building my project during the Build process for Azure DevOps.

It runs locally but fails to run during the build process.

This is to enable Swagger for only Debug and not Prod.

Answer (score 0):

When running msbuild, you have to add /p:DefineConstants="DEBUG" to the command line:

msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:OutputPath="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" /p:DefineConstants="DEBUG"'